# Make div fit next to another div at all times

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs. One of them is functioning as a wrapper for the other two.
Let's call them div1 and div2. Div1 has a fixed width. The width of the wrapper is variable but never less then the width of div1.

Now, how do I make div2 always have the width (width of wrapper - width of div1)?

Here is what I got:

```
.wrapper {
width: 420px; /*Variable but not less then width of div1*/
height: 500px;
border: 2px solid #0000FF;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; /*Fixed*/
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; /*Should be   width of wrapper - width of div1*/
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #00FF00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjhnhtny/10/

Comment: have you looked at flexbox css? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Now at 2024, both answers are outdated. Use flexbox have a better support and control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for two things:

- To set `float: left` on `.div2`
- The CSS **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** function, which can handle subtraction. Specifically, you're looking for `width: calc(100% - (200px + (2px * 2) + (2px * 2)))`, which is `100%` of the`.wrapper`, minus the `width` of `.div1`, along with both sides of both element's `border` width.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 420px; /*Variable but not less then width of div1*/
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #0000FF;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; /*Fixed*/
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - (200px + (2px * 2) + (2px * 2))); /*Should be   width of wrapper - width of div1*/
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #00FF00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you **could** make use of **[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)** so that you only need to modify one property's value (with all elements being automatically adjusted), by setting a variable in `:root` and referencing it with **[`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)**.

Having said that, CSS variables would probably be a bit overkill, but I'll show you how can use them in case you opt for this approach. Try adjusting the `--border-width` in the following, and you'll see that all elements update and resize appropriately :)

```css
:root {
  --width: 200px;
  --border-width: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 420px; /*Variable but not less then width of div1*/
  height: 500px;
  border: var(--border-width) solid #0000FF;
}

.div1 {
  width: var(--width);
  height: 200px; /*Fixed*/
  border: var(--border-width) solid #FF0000;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - (var(--width) + (var(--border-width) * 2) + (var(--border-width) * 2))); /*Should be   width of wrapper - width of div1*/
  height: 200px;
  border: var(--border-width) solid #00FF00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If I have not mistaken your question, you can use a pure css approach.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 420px; /*Variable but not less then width of div1*/
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #0000FF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; /*Fixed*/
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100%; /*Should be   width of wrapper - width of div1*/
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid #00FF00;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```